# Cloud Endpoint exception mapper from GoogleJsonResponseException

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I wonder if there is a library that maps exceptions thrown from cloud endpoints back to `Exception` object on the client side. Exceptions thrown on the server side are represented as a `GoogleJsonResponseException` and contains the full package name of the real cause:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code": 401,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "location": "Authorization",
      "locationType": "header",
      "message": "com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthRequestException: User not logged in",
      "reason": "required"
    }
  ],
  "message": "com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthRequestException: User not logged in"
}
```

I would like to write client code like this:

```
try {
    // call endpoint
} catch (OAuthRequestException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

I think this is possible to write such library. With a code processor and annotations it's feasible to generate client library with appropriate exceptions. Perhaps the client code would not look like the code below but like this one:

```
try {
    Library.mapExceptions(/* call endpoint */);
} catch (OAuthRequestException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Is there something out there that does this job?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about this kind of library, but you can always do:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (IOException) {
   if (e instanceof GoogleJsonResponseException){
      GoogleJsonResponseException ex = e;
      switch (ex.getStatusCode()){
          case 400:
              ...
          case 404:
              ...
          /*and the rest of codes available through endpoints*/
      }
   } else {
      /*Manage other exceptions, maybe connection issues?*/
   }
}
```

Comment: This is what I actually do. Furthermore I have some specific exceptions and I have also to parse the exception type. This code is ugly, that's why I'm looking for some library that handles it in a beautiful manner.